# WordPress: links after changing hosting and domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am changing hosting + domain name for my WordPress site. For example now if its hosted on `201.0.0.1/mysite` and now I want to upload it to `mysite.com`. This is what I did

1. exported database from my cpanel
2. got all files from server using filezilla (`public_html` folder that has Wordpress root folder as well)
3. set permalinks option to default and exported all content from existing site.
4. now planning to create a new database, setup wp-config.php and replace all files in public_html files.

My question is after doing all this will I face any issues regarding page / posts or any other links means it may not happen that I may get some broken links after doing all this. Is there any extra step required with all this mentioned above or is it okay?

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the below steps:

1) First export the sql file.

2) Open downloaded sql file and replace old url with new url like "//www.test.com" replace it with "//www.test2.com".

3) Replace all old paths and save it.

4) upload that sql file in your new site

That's it!